# Java graphic 2D library to draw ER diagrams?

Tags: java, mysql, graphics, er-diagram

I'm looking for a Java 2D graphics library to draw a E-R Diagram from a MySQL database, anyone know something like that?

- With a 2D Java library graphic I need to draw entities, relationships, foreign keys, primary keys, and attributes.
- Optionally, the entities maybe be dragged in the diagram.

I would use Graphics2D for Java? What do you think? Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a look at [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I hope that this library help me. Great documentation and open source... Nice! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to draw E/R diagrams for MySQL, I'd recommend trying [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/).

If your objective is to learn Java 2D or OpenGL, have at it.